# Mysql select with 2 left join shows all records from second left join

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get books (and collections - that I link to a book id) - that were read. I use 2 left joins.

Please see examples below.

**I'm obtaining this result:**

[image]

**I would like to obtain** this list but only the collection that was read in a_books_subcollection. In this results it shows the readtime for all collections and the output is only collection 3.

[image]

**a_books**

[image]

**a_books_subcollection**

[image]

**a_read**

[image]

The contents

```
CREATE TABLE `a_books_subcollection` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `book_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `a_books_subcollection` (`id`, `label`, `book_id`)
VALUES
    (1,'Collection 1',3),
    (2,'Collection 2',3),
    (3,'Collection 3',3);


CREATE TABLE `a_read` (
  `label` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `book_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `readtime` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `a_read` (`label`, `book_id`, `readtime`)
VALUES
    ('Story 1',1,'2020-09-09'),
    ('Collection 3',3,'2020-09-09');


CREATE TABLE `a_books` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_collection` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `a_books` (`id`, `label`, `is_collection`)
VALUES
    (1,'story 1',NULL),
    (2,'story 2',NULL),
    (3,'story 3',1);
```

My query

```
SELECT a_books.* ,a_read.readtime,a_read.label
FROM a_books

LEFT JOIN a_books_subcollection
ON a_books_subcollection.book_id=a_books.id

LEFT JOIN a_read
ON a_books.id=a_read.book_id

ORDER BY a_books.id
```

Comment: Have one doubt. So the snippet-1 is the result you get. But you want the result like it showing in snippet-2.

Comment: What I think your table design is something missing. My suggestions merge both the table a_books and a_books_subcollections the reason behind this they both label is identified with a unique number. So it is easy to get them out you want. OR ELSE you have to write PROCEDURE for this. LIKE IF ELSE condition for label.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.id,
       b.label book_label,
       b.is_collection,
       r.readtime,
       COALESCE(bs.label, b.label) label
FROM a_books b
LEFT JOIN a_books_subcollection bs ON bs.book_id=b.id
LEFT JOIN a_read r ON r.book_id = b.id AND r.label IN (b.label, bs.label)
ORDER BY id, label
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=16860c699b6cea242bca08502dbb9801)

Comment: Hi. This solves the readtime but the second label is always "collection 3"

Comment: @rosia This is a problem of the structure you have posted (more precisely - of the absence of referential information). Your "My query" shows the same. Add foreign keys into your DDLs.

Comment: @rosia Edited. Check - tables joining logic primarily.

Comment: I see. How would you solve this to make a good structure?

Comment: @rosia The relation between books and collections (as I understand) seems to be M:N (each book may belong to a lot of collections and each collection may include a lot of books). If so then you must have separate tables for books and collections, and additional table which stores the link between each separate book and each separate collection this book belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*,c.readtime ,IF(a.is_collection=1,b.label,c.label) 
FROM a_books a
LEFT JOIN a_books_subcollection b ON b.book_id=a.id
LEFT JOIN a_read c on c.book_id=a.id and (c.label=b.label or c.label=a.label)
ORDER BY a.id,b.label
```

maybe this solve your problem, but your field `label` result you want is really ambiguous you want take from table `a_books_subcollection` or `a_read`. i add condition to get label, if data `is_collection` from table `a_books` is `1` get label from table `a_books_subcollection`  else get label from table `a_read`

Answer (score 0):

The table "a_books_subcollection" was joined but never read, consider to remove it.
Also, you have the field "label" in 2 different tables, better to use "AS", like:

```
a_books_subcollection.label AS subcollection_label, a_read.label AS read_label
```

Comment: For completeness, please provide the replacement query